# Function inside function in react.js

Tags: reactjs, service, package

Is there anything like packages/services in React.js ?

I would like to call below function in every component of React.js as packages/services. How can I do that ?

```
function () {
    setToken (token,expiration) {
        localStorage.setItem('token',token)
        localStorage.setItem('expiration',expiration)
    },
    getToken () {
        var token = localStorage.getItem('token')
        var expiration = localStorage.getItem('expiration')

        if(!token || !expiration)
            return null

        if(Date.now() > parseInt(expiration)) {
            this.destroyToken()
            return null
        }
        else {
            return token
        }
    },
    destroyToken () {
        localStorage.removeItem('token')
        localStorage.removeItem('expiration')
    },
    isAuthenticated () {
        if(this.getToken()) {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: export this function using `export default ` and then import this inside your component where you want to use.

Comment: Thanks @Yash. But how can I access this function inside component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sharing the values and functions across the application, you can use the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

You use the `Provider` to provide these functions to the child components and a `Consumer` to access them in the child component.

```js
const AuthenticationContext = React.createContext();
const { Provider, Consumer } = AuthenticationContext;

function Login(props) {
  return (
    <Consumer>
      {
        value=>
        <button onClick={value.login}>Login</button>
      }
    </Consumer>
  );
}

function Logout() {
  return (
    <Consumer>
      {
        value=>
        <button onClick={value.logout}>Logout</button>
      }
    </Consumer>
  );
}

function AnotherComponent() {
  return (
    <Consumer>
      {
        value=>{
          return value.isAuthenticated?
            <p>Logged in</p>:
            <p>Not Logged in</p>
        }
      }
    </Consumer>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.setToken = ()=> {
      this.setState({
        isAuthenticated: true
      });
    }
    this.destroyToken = ()=> {
      this.setState({
        isAuthenticated: false
      });
    }
    this.state = {
      isAuthenticated: false,
      login: this.setToken,
      logout: this.destroyToken
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Provider value={this.state}>
        <Login />
        <Logout />
        <AnotherComponent />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Note: If you would just like the ability to call these functions, you might just export them from this file.

But you cannot write them as a function, that syntax is incorrect.

```
export default {
  setToken: (token,expiration)=>{
    localStorage.setItem('token',token)
    localStorage.setItem('expiration',expiration)
  },
}
```

and in the file you would want to use these,

```
import Auth from 'file';
Auth.setToken()
```

Comment: Thanks @Boy With Silver Wings. I think lower portion of your answer need an edit. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. @abuabu What is the extra content you require in this edit?

Comment: Thanks @Boy With Silver Wings. Could you rewrite this portion `export default {
  setToken (token,expiration) {
    localStorage.setItem('token',token)
    localStorage.setItem('expiration',expiration)
  },
}` ? Is this portion is correct ? error less ?

Comment: @abuabu Got it. Corrected the same

Comment: `export default Auth { }` should I write like this ?

Comment: Nope, you don't need to give it a name. `export default {}` exports an object. When you import it, you can give it any name you like

Answer (score 1):

Inside your component, import your service:

```
import Token from "./services/token.js";
```

token.js

```
export default {
    //token logic
}
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/rmwokj6rrq

Comment: Thanks @Arielle Nguyen. Could please write more code in `token.js` ?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any support of services\packages in react compare to angular where there is because angular is view only, and angular is framework. when you using react you are using vanilla (or not vanilla) js.

In your case, you should do something like this:

const TOKEN_KEY = 'token';
const EXPRIATION_KEY = 'expiration';

```
export function setToken (token,expiration) {
        localStorage.setItem(TOKEN_KEY,token)
        localStorage.setItem(EXPRIATION_KEY ,expiration)
}

export function getToken () {
        var token = localStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY)
        var expiration = localStorage.getItem(EXPRIATION_KEY)

        if(!token || !expiration)
            return null

        if(Date.now() > parseInt(expiration)) {
            this.destroyToken()
            return null
        }
        else {
            return token
        }
}

export function destroyToken () {
        localStorage.removeItem(TOKEN_KEY)
        localStorage.removeItem(EXPRIATION_KEY )
    }


export function isAuthenticated () {
        if(this.getToken()) {
            return true
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

and then, in your components just import the relevant functions

```
import { setToken } from '~yourfilename~';
...
...
setToken(...,...)
```

**NOTE:**
it's seems that the function getToken is used only in private usage (only for those components), if it does, you shouldn't export it.